# Mvx does not exist in the current context

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

```
using MvvmCross.Platform.IoC;
using Acr.UserDialogs;


namespace YourMom.Core
{
    public class App : MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxApplication
    {
        public override void Initialize()
        {
            CreatableTypes()
                .EndingWith("Service")
                .AsInterfaces()
                .RegisterAsLazySingleton();

            Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IUserDialogs>(() => UserDialogs.Instance);

            RegisterAppStart<ViewModels.FirstViewModel>();
        }
    }
}
```

I try to use use dialog plugin for Xamarin mvvmcross. It says to put the registerSingleton code in my PCL app.cs, but i have error saying Mvx is not recognized. I am pretty sure i need to "using" some package i just don't know what. Pls help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess I'm answering my own question yet again.

The one to "import" is MvvmCross.Platform;

So to solve this issue, just add

```
using MvvmCross.Platform;
```

To the top of App.cs.

Comment: I would consider this a typographical error. If you are using a _sane_ IDE like VS or XS it would also suggest to resovle this and add this as a using.

Comment: I am using XamarinStudio. But I don't get any suggestions from it. Just fail when trying to run.

Comment: That works. I'm totally new to Xamarin Studio. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: This is similar in Visual Studio where you use CTRL + . or press the light bulb.

Comment: I never used VS before. I come from 100% XCode (iOS mostly) background. I appreciate your comment. TQ sir.